# Thymeleaf not recognizing public enum in a class

Tags: java, enums, thymeleaf

I have this enum inside a class "myclass" which is inside "mypackage".

```
public enum InputError {
TIME_PERIOD_GIVEN;
}
```

and supposedly, the Thymeleaf template should reference it and compare it as:

```
<th:block th:if="${somevar == T(mypackage.myclass.InputError).TIME_PERIOD_GIVEN}"
```

It does not. It displays in debug the error:

```
Caused by: ognl.NoSuchPropertyException: mypackage.myclass.InputError
```

Any idea on what is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you need to use T here. Can't you just put the enum directly there `mypackage.myclass.InputError.TIME_PERIOD_GIVEN` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that but it still gives same error.

Comment: I've tested it, and what you have works for me. There is something else going on. Why is your `myclass` lowercase if it's a java class?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:
`th:if="${somevar == T(mypackage.myclass.InputError).MONDAY}"`

Make sure you put the correct package name.

Answer (score 1):

I would use String instead of Java Enum, because it is ugly to depend on an a package. It is error prone, especially if you will move your enum class in another package.

```
<th:block th:if="${somevar == TIME_PERIOD_GIVEN}"
```

and in java :

```
model.put("somevar", InputError.TIME_PERIOD_GIVEN.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `T()` syntax is only available if you are using Spring. When using Spring, the OGNL (Object-Graph Navigation Language) syntax is replaced by SpringEL which enables the `T()` construct. See the [Thymeleaf
documentation.](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#variables)

Using OGNL you can use the following syntax for [calling static methods](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html):

```html
<th:block th:if="${somevar == @mypackage.myclass.InputError@TIME_PERIOD_GIVEN}"></th>
```